# Geodesic shape on the 2-sphere with Lorentzian metric

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the 2-Sphere.

With Riemannian metric on it, signature (1,1), the geodesic is the great circle.

But assuming we can put Lorentzian metric on it, with signature (-1,1), how the geodesic will change from the great circle and looks like?

Comment: The sphere $S^2$ does not admit a Lorentzian metric, so we can’t answer your question (or rather we can give any answer and it is correct because we’re speaking vacuously).

Comment: So the assumption is wrong. Is it trivial that we can't put that metric on the sphere?

Comment: It’s not really trivial, but also not crazy difficult. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47446).

Comment: Great, so related to the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: So, the 2-sphere is useful for the visual intuition about the curvature of space only.

But the 2-sphere is useless and misleading for the visual intuition about the curvature of spacetime.

Comment: Correct, you’re going to have to work very hard to overcome years of training with Euclidean geometry of lengths and angles, particularly the notion of orthogonality (e.g. existence of lightlike vectors, the triangle inequality pointing the other way around for future-directed timelike vectors etc…so far this is all applicable even in the flat case of Minkowski space. Going to the curved case requires more effort if you want to ‘visualize’).

Comment: The theorem you shared, basically says, a 3-sphere spacetime is geometrically possible, but a 4-sphere spacetime is impossible in principle?

Comment: For each $n\geq 1$, the sphere $S^{2n+1}$ admits a Lorentzian metric, while $S^{2n}$ does not. No need to say ‘in principle’.

Comment: I used "in principle" to note that even before considering energy-matter on the spacetime.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148102/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-vvm).